# Site content shifts vertically on certain pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

I'm in the process of building a new website for my wife's business, using Squarespace. Don't tell her, since it's one of her Christmas presents. :)

However, I'm experiencing a weird issue. About half of the pages on the site include content from a third-party widget called Healcode. Those pages have a strange jerkiness to them on pageload, where the logo and navbar move around -- ultimately winding up in the right spot, but looking bad while doing so. Pages that don't have a third-party widget don't have this jerkiness.

Example of page that jerks: https://coconditioning.squarespace.com/yoga-classes/
Example of page that doesn't jerk: https://coconditioning.squarespace.com/private-coaching/

The Healcode widget is javascript code that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  healcode_widget_id = "ay12237c4nc";
  healcode_widget_name = "schedules";
  healcode_widget_type = "mb";
  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='https://www.healcode.com/javascripts/hc_widget.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
  // Healcode Schedule Widget for Conscious Conditioning L.L.C. : Weekly Schedule New
</script>
<noscript>Please enable Javascript in order to get <a href="https://www.healcode.com" target="_blank">HealCode</a> functionality</noscript>
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you loading this javascript on starting of page? As javascript is loads synchronously it may lead to jerkiness

Comment: Honestly, all I am doing is injecting that code I pasted into the question in the appropriate spot on the page. I don't understand why the widget content would cause the divs above it to shift around. Hence my question.

Comment: On the page that doesn't shift, there is an inline style on the `<div id="bannerImage">` element with `margin-bottom: 116px` that is preventing the content area from shifting. Try disabling JavaScript to debug the problem; it's unrelated to 3rd-party content.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing this. Both of those pages have this:

    <div id="bannerImage" class="default-background default-background-page-thumbnail" >

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the page until the `body` loads:

```
<body style = 'display: none'; />
```

And in your javascript, adding `window.onload()`:

```
healcode_widget_id = "ay12237c4nc";
  healcode_widget_name = "schedules";
  healcode_widget_type = "mb";
  document.write( unescape("%3Cscript src='https://www.healcode.com/javascripts/hc_widget.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
  // Healcode Schedule Widget for Conscious Conditioning L.L.C. : Weekly Schedule New

window.onload = function()
 {
   document.body.style.display = 'block';
 };
```

Also, is `document.write()` the best solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use document.write if possible as with document.write JS parser doesn't know where to put it. at best, the browser will ignore it. at worst, it could write over the top of your current document. Use `appendChild`

```
function loadHealCodeScript () {

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://www.healcode.com/javascripts/hc_widget.js' 
    document.body.appendChild(script);

}

window.onload = loadHealCodeScript; // load healcode after page has been loaded
```

The jittering effect is happening because the healcode is loading its script before the page has completely loaded. If possible place all you javascripts after the body tag rather than head

As suggested by google also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#asynch

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this, but it caused the healcode javascript not to execute.